# How to simulate the delete key on UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm creating an application on the iPad. I create a custom keyboard using `UITextField`'s `inputView` property. To insert text at the cursor position, I use the copy & paste method (http://dev.ragfield.com/2009/09/insert-text-at-current-cursor-location.html), which works fine. Now, I want to create the delete key. The code that I'm using is:

```
if (textField.text.length > 0) {
    textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:textField.text.length-1];
}
```

However, as you may know, it only deletes the last character no matter where the cursor is. Does anyone know a better solution?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 18):

Just call `[textField deleteBackward]`. It takes care of cursor position and highlight for you.

Swift:

```
textField.deleteBackward()
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty good solution. Can't believe I missed this. Takes care of emoji too. Thanks. :)

Comment: Not sure that this works on iPad, I'm currently seeing it work on iPhone but not iPad...

Comment: Superb solution in a single line...Great Job @GoldenJoe

Answer (score 5):

I've got it!
This is my delegate method implementation for the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method.

---

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange) range replacementString:(NSString *) string {
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"⌫"]) {
        // NSLog(@"Backspace Pressed");
        NSMutableString *text = [textField.text mutableCopy];
        // NSLog(@"Length: %d Location: %d", range.length, range.location);
        if (range.length > 0) {
            [text deleteCharactersInRange:range];
        }
        if (range.length == 0 && range.location != 0) {
            NSRange backward = NSMakeRange(range.location - 1, 1);
            // NSLog(@"Length: %d Location: %d", backward.length, backward.location);
            [text deleteCharactersInRange:backward];
        }
        // NSLog(@"%@", text);
        textField.text = text;
        return NO;
    } else {return YES;}
}
```

It works hand in hand with the [UIPasteboard method](http://dev.ragfield.com/2009/09/insert-text-at-current-cursor-location.html) for getting text into a `UITextField`, which means that you have to link up your delete key to a method that pastes an arbitrary unicode character into your textfield (such as `⌫`), and when the delegate method is called, you recognise that the replacement string is that specific character.

From there, you either delete the characters in `range` from your mutable string of the textField's text if there is an active selection, or you grab the previous character from the range if there is no selection, just a caret.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party (again ;-)... With iOS 5, `UITextField` conforms to the [`UITextInput` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput), which extends `UITextField` with some helpful methods and properties, including the `selectedTextRange` property, which is the equivalent of `selectedRange` in `UITextView`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an alternative solution using a undocumented API: `selectionRange`. I don't know if this will pass Apple's review but as written it won't make the app crash if the method is not available and does not give warnings too :)

This is a category on `UITextField:`

```
- (void)deleteBackward{
    @try{
        //check current selected range
        NSRange selectedRange = [[self valueForKey:@"selectionRange"] rangeValue];
        if (selectedRange.location == NSNotFound) selectedRange = NSMakeRange([[self text] length], 0);
        if (selectedRange.location < 1) return;

        //delete one char
        NSRange deleteRange = (selectedRange.length>0)?selectedRange:NSMakeRange(selectedRange.location-1,1);
        self.text = [self.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:deleteRange withString:@""];

        //adjust the selected range to reflect the changes
        selectedRange.location = deleteRange.location;
        selectedRange.range.length = 0;
        [self setValue:[NSValue valueWithRange:range] forKey:@"selectionRange"];
     }@catch (NSException *exception) {
          NSLog(@"failed but catched. %@", exception);
     }@finally {}
}
```

#### UPDATE: 2011/11/17

in iOS5 UITextField and UITextView conform to [UITextInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol (which conforms to [UIKeyInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIKeyInput)) so you can do `[textField deleteBackward];` which will do exactly the same as `Del` key in the keyboard, `[textField insertText:@"text"];` which will insert text and update the caret position correctly, etc.

So, for compatibility purposes, probably what you want to do similar to this:

```
- (void) myDeleteBackward
{
    if ([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInput)]) {
        // iOS5 and later
        [textField deleteBackward];
        // Or do below line if you are not deploy-targeting 5.0 or above and want to avoid warnings
        //[textField performSelector:@selector(deleteBackward)];
    } else {
        // iOS4 and older versions
        // Do the trick :)
        @try{
        ...
        }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Know if this passes Apple review? It looks like a good solution for me

Comment: It worths trying :) I think it really depends on the application. Sometimes they allow apps with undocumented APIs.

Comment: On iphone simulator iOS 4.3, UITextField doesn't response selector:`deleteBackward` but it responses `insertText:`.??????

Answer (score 2):

Consider switching to a `UITextView`, which has a `selectedRange` property for getting the currently selected range of characters or the cursor location if nothing is selected. Unfortunately, `UITextField` does not have this method, and I have not found another way to find the cursor location.

The documentation for the `selectedRange` property can be found here [here on Apple's website](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/selectedRange). It consists of an `NSRange` in which `selectedRange.location` is the cursor location and `selectedRange.length` is the number of selected characters (or zero if nothing is selected.) Your code will have to look something like this:

```
textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:textView.selectedRange withString:@""];
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you very much. However, I'm using the UITextField in UISearchBar and I don't think I can change it to UITextView. Anyway, I will try implementing my own search bar using UITextView. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

A UITextView has a `selectedRange` property.  Given that you could build a range to use with the following code:

```
textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:?? withString:@""];
```

A UITextField has no such range property.  Obviously it has a `_selectionRange` member but that is private.

I think your choices are either to switch to a UITextView or prevent having the cursor anywhere but at the end of the text and using your current code.

You can always submit a bug report to Apple requesting that they document `selectedRange` for UITextField, or ask for special permission to access the field directly.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, a problem is that I'm using UISearchBar and it only contains a UITextField. I may implement my own search bar using UITextView, but there are some features that I miss in the Apple's seach bar, such as the scope filter and the appearance of the textfield (i.e. very rounded corners.) Anyway, thank you very much. I will try your suggestions. I never known that we can ask for permission to use private APIs.

Comment: You could try textView.layer.cornerRadius for the rounded corners.  It would take some work, but you may be able to place a text view directly over the search bar, so the text view has focus but is otherwise clear and it looks like the search bar has focus.

Answer (score 0):

Holy necro, Batman!  Here's a much simpler answer for iOS 3.2 and later.  Do this in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` or some other method that has access to the delete button:

```
[self.myDeleteButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(deleteBackward) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

This is the same way the system keyboard's delete key works: it sends the `deleteBackward` message along the responder chain.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the position behind the cursor, you can use `textField.deleteBackward()`

This is what I use in Swift 5 when I want to get the result without deleting text from the `UITextField`

```swift
extension UITextField {
    /// simulates removing a character from 1 position behind the cursor and returns the result
    func backSpace() -> String {
        guard var text = text, // local text property, matching textField's text
              let selectedRange = selectedTextRange,
              !text.isEmpty
        else { return "" }
        
        let offset = offset(from: beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
        
        let index = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: offset-1)
        // this doesn't remove text from the textField, just the local text property
        text.remove(at: index)
        return text
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this `if (UITextField.text.length > 0) { [UITextField deleteBackward]; }` :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
if (txtTotal.text.length > 0) {
        txtTotal.text = [txtTotal.text substringToIndex:txtTotal.text.length-1];
    }
```

Comment: downvoted and reported. The question is about how to delete any symbol, not the last one only