# How can I get UITextFieldDelegate.shouldChangeCharactersInRange to fire with custom inputView?

Tags: ios, delegates, uitextfield

I have a custom keyboard that I'm using to edit the text in `mytextField` and it works great. However, I can never get the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate to execute using my custom keyboard. It does execute when I use my actual keyboard(obviously not the default iPhone keyboard, since I'm set mytextField.inputView = numberPad.view). What should I do to cause the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate to fire using the custom keyboard? BTW, the custom keyboard is just a bunch of buttons.

```
- (void) numberPadPressed: (UIButton *)sender {
    [mytextField insertText:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag] stringValue]];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *resultingString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];
    NSLog(@"shouldChangeCharactersInRange: %@", resultingString);
    return true;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mytextField.text = @"";
    mytextField.inputView = numberPad.view;
    mytextField.delegate = self;
    [mytextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You will never get the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` called with a custom keyboard.

What you can get is the event `UIControlEventEditingChanged` of the `UITextField`. So instead of relying on `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method (which is known to be buggy in addition), you should rely on this event, that will be fired each time the user changes the content of the text field.

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(myTextfieldChangedMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

If you modify yourself the text field with your custom keyboard, just call this method to notify all listeners of the event `UIControlEventEditingChanged`.

```
[textField sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Your 'forControlEvents' should match your 'sendActionsForControlEvents'

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sorry, misunderstood your question previously.

Your text field calls `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` when it gets input from the *system keyboard*, giving you an opportunity to determine whether the text should actually display (for example you could implement it to recognize a shortcut and insert some longer text). But the text field doesn't recognize input from your custom view as text input.

If you have a custom inputView, you don't need to invoke this method--just update the text field directly from your IBAction:

```
- (IBAction) numberPadPressed: (UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *newText = [[mytextField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:[mytextField selectedRange] withString:string];
    [mytextField setText:newText];
}
```

Comment: I just tested using your suggestion above, but still shouldChangeCharactersInRange did not fire when numberPadPressed is called. I think we are on the right track...

Comment: How will I calculate the range? Is there a way to move the cursor at any particular position in a TextField?

Comment: I updated the code sample. Use [mytextField selectedRange] to get the selected range, which will just be an insertion point if there's no selection, or will be a range of characters if there's a selection.

Comment: selectedRange is not available in UITextField. It is a private member. But no worries I'm on a new path on what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I ran into the same problem in needing to support pre 5.0 devices. If you override insertText: by following the instructions from Rob at http://dev.ragfield.com/2009/09/insert-text-at-current-cursor-location.html then you will get shouldChangeCharactersInRange to fire every time.

If you then need to support the backspace key like I did you can use the answer from @cormacrelf at [How to simulate the delete key on UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007911/how-to-simulate-the-delete-key-on-uitextfield)

The only snafu I haven't been able to work around is that when you delete a character from the middle of the string the cursor jumps back to the end of the string.