# shouldChangeCharactersInRange cannot be called after set text for UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am using UITextField to input value, set its delegate to parent view controller, after use textField.text = @"some text" to set text value for text field, delegate function textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: cannot be called any more.
How to prevent this or allow this function be called after setText?
Thanks in advance,
Sorry for my poor English.
UPDATE : textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: cannot be called when i tap "backspace" since 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

That method isn't supposed to be called when you set the text in code. Why would you want it to -- you are passing in the exact text you want, so there should be no need to change or validate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the method in the delegate stops being called completely, setting the text field is not the reason.  You would need to be doing something else to cause that.  As @rdelmar says, it won't be called for the assignment but it will be called for future edits.  For example, if I write...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.textField.text = @"View will appear";
}
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"Replacement: %@", string);
    return YES;
}
```

...I see...

```
2012-11-25 21:02:34.456 Hello World[6669:c07] Replacement: H
2012-11-25 21:02:34.954 Hello World[6669:c07] Replacement: e
2012-11-25 21:02:35.838 Hello World[6669:c07] Replacement: l
2012-11-25 21:02:35.974 Hello World[6669:c07] Replacement: l
2012-11-25 21:02:36.162 Hello World[6669:c07] Replacement: o
```

Comment: I am implementing delegate function like this :
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]){
        textField.text = nil;    // or = @"abc..";
    }
    return YES;
}
after tapped "backspace" key, this delegate function cannot be called any more (if setText in other delegate function, it happend too)

Comment: This issue is answered by @jptsetung, but I want to find solution to prevent its.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674023/how-can-i-get-uitextfielddelegate-shouldchangecharactersinrange-to-fire-with-cus

Comment: Sorry, it happened if I type "backspace" one more time.