# "Key Equivalent" input similar to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, nstextfield

In Xcode, when you are setting a keyboard shortcut, there is a nice control that helps you out:

[image: UI Control]

I feel like I could reproduce it by extending a `NSTextField`, but I also feel like it may be something someone else has done before. I've done some searching but have not been able to come up with anything.

Does anyone happen to know where I may find a similar component, or possibly have any suggestions should I attempt it myself?

Comment: Did not get your question?exactly what you want to acheive??

Comment: @hussainShabbir OP want NSTextField same as key equivalent.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007911/how-to-simulate-the-delete-key-on-uitextfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980187/user-assigned-key-equivalents), I found [ShortcutRecorder](https://github.com/Kentzo/ShortcutRecorder). Basically what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes samething you can do in the textfield as well:-

1. You have to make button programmatically inside that set keyEquivalent there.
2. Set action and target programmatically inside button.
3. Inside method set your textfield to be becomeFirstResponder. So that whenever user press shortcut your textfield will be selected.